# How to use js code to redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

My app is use react+redux, I used to `this.context.router` API to redirect my page, but the react official suggest we needn't user the `context` API, and I also used to `history` to redirect page, and then I will get a warning from the `console` "Warning: [react-router] props.history and context.history are deprecated. Please use context.router.", so how can I use js code to redirect

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of `react-router`

In `v4` you can think of [redirection as a component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#redirect):

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.isLoggedIn ? (
      <p>You're logged in!!</p>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    )
  }
}
```

in `v3` I would recommend using `browserHistory`

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) browserHistory.replace('/login')
  }

  render() {
   if (this.props.isLoggedIn) return (<p>You're logged in!!</p>)
   return null 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I want to use js code to redirect pager such as `browserHistory.replace`, absolutely use the `<Redirect  />` can also redirect , but I can't use the label, so I use the `history` API but I will get a warning 'Warning: [react-router] props.history and context.history are deprecated. Please use context.router'